# 'Delay' is not a member of Task .NET

Tags: .net, async-await, task

Why am I getting

> 'Delay' is not a member of 'Task'.

error? I already used

```
Imports System.Threading.Tasks

Private Async Sub InitializeIceberg()
    If Not Await CheckDatabaseConnection() Then
        Await Task.Delay(1000)
    End If
End Sub
```

Did I miss anything?

[The error.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1I843.png)

Comment: Are you using .NET 4. Back then, there was no Task.Delay.

Comment: I see. So that's the problem. What's the minimum .NET version? Thanks!

Comment: I didnt get that. What do you meant by minimum .Net version. If you want a delay in this one try a library by microsoft :https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Comment: This delay was added in 4.5. I am not sure if you can upgrade it to that. If you cant, use this https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.Bcl.Async/

Comment: Another way to get this warning is having another identifier named "Task" or "task" in your code.  Right-click "task" and pick Go To Definition to see it.